# put multi div and another multi div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a div in another div using js. I found a solution can do this but just put 1 div in div. Below html is my situation.

For example:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span class="outer_part">
        </span>
        <div class="inner_part">1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="outer_part">
        </span>
        <div class="inner_part">2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="outer_part">
        </span>
        <div class="inner_part">3
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Result:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span class="outer_part">
           <div class="inner_part">1</div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="outer_part">
           <div class="inner_part">2</div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="outer_part">
           <div class="inner_part">3</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

I found solution but not work

```
<script>
    $('.inner_part').appendTo('span.outer_part');
</script>
```

Comment: Which is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you appending all the `.inner_part` elements to all the `.outer_part` elements, but you only need to do a portion of that.

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop over **all** the `.inner_parts`, and attach each to its previous sibling, which is the `.outer_part`.

```
// loop over all inner parts
$('.inner_part').each(function() {

  var innerPart = $(this);
  var outerPart = innerPart.prev(); // inner part's previous sibling is the outer part

  innerPart.appendTo(outerPart);
});
```

Or, shorter:

```
$('.inner_part').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).prev());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get element by the ID, then add html inside of it to add a div in this case or anything you want.

```js
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += '<div class="inner_part">1</div>';
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```